# Get date, hour and minute as separate variables from a datetimestamp in PHP

Tags: php

In PHP if I have a variable ($getTimeStamp) that follows the format 0000-00-00 00:00:00 (i.e. 2013-09-26 13:06:00).

What is the easiest way to get the date ($getDate), hour ($getHour) and minute ($getMinute) as separate variables?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: you should always use Objective PHP instead of procedural. Learn and use OOP always ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest way is to use PHP [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class

```
$getTimeStamp = '2013-09-26 13:06:00';
$date = new \DateTime($getTimeStamp);

$dateString = $date->format('Y-m-d');
$hourString = $date->format('H');
$minuteString = $date->format('i');
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not timestamp ;) Check what `time()` function returns, that's how timestamp looks like.

You can use something like that:

```
$time = strtotime($getTimeStamp);
$getDate = date('Y-m-d', $time);
$getHour = date('H', $time);
$getMinute = date('i', $time);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve this using -

```
$time = strtotime($getTimeStamp);

$getDate = date('Y-m-d', $time);
$getHour = date('H', $time);
$getMinute = date('i', $time);
```

Have a look at **[time()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)** and **[date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)**.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since all you want is really to parse some text this would be the shortest way:

```
list($date, $hour, $minute) = preg_split('/[ :]/', $getTimeStamp);
```

There is no real reason to involve the date/time classes if you are not manipulating dates or calculating timestamps.

**[Live example](http://ideone.com/70rPKh)**.

Answer (score 0):

Just one answer using the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $getTimeStamp);

$date = $dt->format('Y-m-d ');
$hour = $dt->format('H');
$minutes = $dt->format('i');
```